# Vault: Get current backends

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Is there anyway, using cli, to obtain the list of current secret mounted backends?

Exist a way in order to list auth methods: `vault auth list`, but I've don't quite get how to list current mounted secret backends.

I've tried with `vault list /`, but I've not got luck so far.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can list the current secret engines with this:
`vault secrets list`

From the command line:

```
Usage: vault secrets <subcommand> [options] [args]

This command groups subcommands for interacting with Vault's secrets engines.
Each secret engine behaves differently. Please see the documentation for more information.

List all enabled secrets engines:

  $ vault secrets list
```